# Parcel tries to install custom vue components from npm

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, npm-install, parceljs

When I run `parcel watch index.js`,  I see a console error (shown below). Why is it trying to use `npm` to load my component?

```
npm ERR! 404 Not found : MyComponent
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'MyComponent' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 Your package name is not valid, because 
npm ERR! 404  1. name can no longer contain capital letters
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/jonny/Projects/invoices/npm-debug.log
  /home/jonny/Projects/invoices/src/App.vue:7:40: Failed to install Invoice.
    at PromiseQueue.install [as process] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parcel-bundler/src/utils/installPackage.js:46:11)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

App.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{name}}
        <my-component></my-component>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import Vue from "vue";
    import MyComponent from "MyComponent"

    export default Vue.extend({
        data: function() {
            return {
                name: 'Hello World!',
            }
        },
        components: {
            MyComponent // This line is the problem!
        }
    });
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

MyComponent.vue

```
<template>
    <div >
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default MyComponent = Vue.component('my-component', {
        data: function () {
            return {
                myvalue: 0
            }
        },
    });
</script>
```

index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import {default as App} from './App';

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(App),
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import path should be relative for local files.

Parcel's [module resolution](https://parceljs.org/module_resolution.html) uses the standard Node algorithm, where plain module names (`MyComponent` in this case) would cause a lookup in the `node_modules` directory (or direct to NPM in Parcel's case).

But `MyComponent` is actually a local file (`MyComponent.vue`). Assuming `MyComponent.vue` is in the same directory as `App.vue`, the relative path would be `./MyComponent.vue`:

```
// import MyComponent from "MyComponent" // DON'T DO THIS
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent"
```

Comment: @Jonathan No problem:)